# Container checkpointing on Minikube with CRIO

Tags: minikube, checkpointing, cri-o, criu

We are trying to take a snapshot of a container with the [Kubernetes Container checkpointing feature](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/12/05/forensic-container-checkpointing-alpha/).

**Environment**: minikube

**runtime-contaner**: crio

We tried the following:

1. Start a new profile in minikube setting the ContainerCheckpoint feature flag:

   minikube start --container-runtime=crio --feature-gates=ContainerCheckpoint=true -p criupoc
2. Review configuration to make sure that the feature gate is setup correctly:

   vim ~/.minikube/profiles/criupoc/config.json
3. Created nginx pod and verify that it's running:

   kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/simple-pod.yaml
   kubectl get pods
4. Try the checkpointing feature as advised in the documentation (already linked above):

   curl --insecure --cert ~/.minikube/profiles/criupoc/client.crt --key ~/.minikube/profiles/criupoc/client.key -X POST "https://<MINIKUBEIP_PLACEHOLDER>:10250/checkpoint/default/nginx/nginx"

**Expected**: checkpoint is taken

**Actual**: checkpointing of default/nginx/nginx failed (rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown method CheckpointContainer for service runtime.v1.RuntimeService)

**Notes**:

- I tried this with the docker container-runtime (in minikube) too,
  with the same results. As per containerd, it seems like it doesn't
  support CRIU yet.
- [This example](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/12/05/forensic-container-checkpointing-alpha/), suggests to use also the flag --enable-criu-support=true within cri-o but I have no idea how to set it through minikube or in any other ways.

**QUESTION**:
Could you please provide some insight into this? How could I fix this error or alter my procedure to get a snapshot of the nginx container?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that the feature is newly launched, I was only able to gather documentation using containerd. Linking here the [documentation](https://thenewstack.io/grab-a-snapshot-of-your-container-image-with-checkpoint/) where the steps provided on taking a snapshot of container image with checkpoint in containerd.

Attaching here as well a reference [documentation](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu) about CRIU that you can connect yourself for further updates.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't really solve the issue as it doesn't even mention minikube....